# Xamarin Android Resources NotFoundException ZXingNetMobile

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, zxing

I attempt to use *ZXingNetMobile* to scan QR Code in Android, but I get this error:

[image: Error opening scanner]

This is the function that I use:

```
public async Task<string> ScanQrCode()
{
    var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
    var result = await scanner.Scan();
    return result.Text;
}
```

And this is my configuration:

[image: Android Project Configuration]

[image: SDK Manager]

**EDIT**

Here is my packages.config:

[image]

Comment: My previous answer might help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451758/can-someone-actually-explain-the-workings-of-resource-designer-cs/40456727#40456727 It seems like it's looking for the `v7.AppCompat` `abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha.9.png` resource and it's not being found(Inside the v4 folder...?). Can you edit your answer and include the NuGet link? What NuGet version is this library? The current stable seems to have a dependency only on `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (>= 23.0.1.3)`. What does your `packages.config` look like?

Comment: Was my own mistake, I had exclude the file Resource.Designer.cs.

Comment: @ggarciasoft Please post your observation as an answer and mark it as accepted. Otherwise, people, including myself, will open the question since it hasn't been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Was my own mistake, I had exclude the file Resource.Designer.cs.

Comment: I am facing the same issue from past two weeks how did you fixed it?

Comment: I included the file Resource.Designer.cs

Comment: In my case Resource.Designer.cs is already included in project. Do you know any other reason for this issue?