# Xamarin.Android upgrade to API 24

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an existing Xamarin.Android application that I built to support up to API 19 a few years back. I now want to update the codebase to support API 24 and running into a whirlwind of problems.

I have updated all packages and components in my codebase so that they are all on the latest and greatest. Now when I do a compile I get several hundred errors complaining that attributes in the Resources.designer.cs file are not defined. Below is an example of just one of these compilation errors.

```
[PATH_TO_PROJECT]/Resources/Resource.designer.cs(98,98): Error CS0117: `[PROJECT_NAMESPACE].Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for `barSize' (CS0117) ([PROJECT])
```

This line within the Resource.designer.cs file is highlighted as an error.

```
global::GooglePlayServices.Resource.Attribute.barSize = global::[PROJECT_NAMESPACE].Resource.Attribute.barSize;
```

The vast majority of these issues seem to be coming from some linking between my styles and Google Play Services. I have updated all of my GPS packages to the latest 29.0.0.2, and I still have these errors.

I have also made sure to delete all existing "bin" and "obj" folders within my app codebase as well as everything from the `~/.local/share folder`.

Does anyone have any idea how to help me resolve these issues? I'm worried Nougat doesn't support the `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` theme  and will have todo a full Theme redesign :(

Thanks!

-- EDIT --

Here is the content of my packages.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AWS-Mobile-SDK-Xamarin-Beta" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid44" />
  <package id="Humanizer" version="1.37.7" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="sqlite-net" version="1.0.8" targetFramework="MonoAndroid44" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="24.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat" version="24.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI" version="24.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils" version="24.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment" version="24.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat" version="24.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="24.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="24.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="24.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette" version="24.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="24.2.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads" version="29.0.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base" version="29.0.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement" version="29.0.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm" version="29.0.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location" version="29.0.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps" version="29.0.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Measurement" version="29.0.0.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Insights" version="1.10.4.112" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Can you add your `packages.config` as it's not apparent which GPS packages you are using off first glance.

Comment: Hi, I added the content so my packages.config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was causing the errors. There were some cached package files being stored in a "Shared" library that I have in my application codebase that I didn't know were there. There were also some cached package files in the directory "~/.local/share/Xamarin" that had to be removed also. I also had to update all of my Xamarin.Android packages to the latest versions as well as all of the Android SDK and tools. Once I did all of this it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Between `Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` version 22.2.1 and version 23, this field was removed:

https://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/23/changes/android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.html

Thus if you are referencing it in your application, you will need to either not use it, or find the equivalent item. From the `Added Fields` diff, it seems like a logical fit might be `barLength`. If you aren't using it inside your application, another reference you have is and you will have to update that reference to ensure it supports the latest `Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` version.

Comment: OK, so is it not related to Google Play Services? From the error above it looks like GPS is trying to reference it. I've tried to update GPS to the latest and greatest, but that still doesn't work. Do you think it's the Theme is no longer supported?

Comment: Another question is all of the errors are coming from my Resource.design.cs. Since this is a generated file I need to find the actual place in code these properties are referenced. From what I see in my resource designer it looks like they are coming from Google Play Services. All of my GPS packages are on the latest 29.0.0.1 version, so with that being the latest how could I fix the issue? Such a strange one :(

Comment: If you can upload a sample project it might be easier to pinpoint the issue. It sounds like you might have an old cache of the `Resource.designer.cs`. See my answer on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451758/can-someone-actually-explain-the-workings-of-resource-designer-cs/40456727#40456727

Comment: Yeah, I'm working on a sample project to see if I get the same issue. If I am able to replicate in a new project then I'll upload it.

Answer (score -1):

The only solution I found was to comment all the lines, like you say there are hundreds of lines to comment so I made a java script to comment them:

```
package com.packagename;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;

public class YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        ArrayList<Integer> listaLineas = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        try {
            
            String sCurrentLine;
            String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\ErrorLog.txt"));
            
            int fileLineNumber = 0;
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(sCurrentLine.contains("Resource.designer.cs")){
                        String targetLineNumber = sCurrentLine.substring(sCurrentLine.lastIndexOf("designer.cs") + "designer.cs".length(), sCurrentLine.lastIndexOf("Active")).replaceAll("\\s+","");
                        listaLineas.add(Integer.parseInt(targetLineNumber));
                }
                fileLineNumber++;
            }
            removeFileLines(listaLineas, workingDir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
    }
    
    public static void removeFileLines (ArrayList<Integer> listaLineas, String workingDirPath){
        try{
            File inputFile = new File(workingDirPath + "\\Resource.designer.cs");
            File tempFile = new File(workingDirPath + "\\Resource.designer.cs.temp");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
            String currentLine;
            int targetFileLine = 1;
            while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if(!listaLineas.contains(targetFileLine)){
                    writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }else{
                    writer.write("//" + currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    System.out.println("Line " + targetFileLine + " commented");
                }
                targetFileLine++;
            }
            writer.close(); 
            reader.close();         
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // do nothing
        }   
    }
}
```

You just need to compile it with

> & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\javac.exe' -d . .\YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME.java

And in the same folder create a `ErrorLog.txt` file, when you get the error copy all (select one, Ctrl + A and Ctrl + V) the error lines from the Visual Studio "Error List" to the `ErrorLog.txt` file and the `Resource.designer.cs` file to the folder and execute the script with:

> java.exe -cp . com.packagename.YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME

It will generate a new `Resource.designer.cs.temp` file in the same folder, copy its content to your project `Resource.designer.cs` file and continue with the process of compilation.

The script can be improved to auto get the files but I didn't need it.

Comment: If I just remove the Resources.designer.cs file wouldn't this all be unnecessary? Is there something else that is cached that the aapt process is using?

Comment: if you remove the whole file you maybe lose the link with the resources of your app so probably will fail

Comment: Yes it did fail overall when I did that, but it generated a new Resource.designer.cs file with the same issue. So your saying by commenting out all offending lines the aatp process will finish this resulting in an updated resource file?

Comment: Commenting out the lines in a `Resource.designer.cs / R.java` file is only a workaround to `Build` your project. If your application uses any of those resources at runtime it will fail to locate the resource. It is recommended by google to not touch generated files. > Caution: You should never modify the R.java file by hand—it is generated by the aapt tool when your project is compiled. Any changes are overridden next time you compile.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought but at this time I'm willing to try anything. If I delete the resource file it should autogenerste right? If that's the case could there be a cache holding on to the older references? I've deleted the file and still the same issue.

Comment: I have also deleted every build file and package I can think of. Even the ones in the shared folder at ~/local/shared/Xamarin

Comment: With this script you are going to have a Resource.designer.cs file with the problematic lines commented so you can continue compiling, but as said by @JonDouglas if one of those lines (library objects) is used by your app you will keep having problems.