# Where find the ViewID

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Im working with an android App. I see the line on the `MainActivity.cs`

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    Instance = this;
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    _locationText = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtLocation);

    RegisterService();
}
```

And the definition for a constant `txtLocation`  on the `ResourceDesigner.cs`

```
public partial class Id
{       
    // aapt resource value: 0x7f040000
    public const int txtLocation = 2130968576; //where this number came from?

    static Id()
    {
        global::Android.Runtime.ResourceIdManager.UpdateIdValues();
    }

    private Id()
    {
    }
}
```

**So where is that id came from?**

On the Main.axml I can see the control is created.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtLocation"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

But dont understand how `android:id="@+id/txtLocation"` become `2130968576`

Comment: This may help as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451758/can-someone-actually-explain-the-workings-of-resource-designer-cs/40456727#40456727

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those resource ids are generated by the Android build tool `aapt` / `aapt2` and that creates the Java `R` file.

Re: [Accessing Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html)

The output in turn is parsed by the MSBuild `JavaResourceParser` task (in `Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks` utilities)

Re: [JavaResourceParser.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/10d1213bff2251f6da7f7935427841dfdde96b9e/src/Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks/Utilities/JavaResourceParser.cs)

Comment: Need more information what is `R`. Where I look for those generated id?

Comment: Click on the Android resource link in my answer.

Comment: I did. They explain there is a R class but dont know what is that

Comment: The Java `R` class (and matching C# `Resource`) represents a list of all the resources in your app. Those resource ids are used to resource  ("find") elements at runtime, used by layouts, user code, etc...

Comment: Yes but where is? How I look the generated id? And what mean `android:id="@+id/txtLocation"` ??

Comment: At runtime? Or compile time?

Comment: lol. .... I dont know I new at this. I just want add a textbox to  print a result :(

Comment: `@+id/txtLocation` is a human readable representation of the integer value that is assigned to it. This is mapping done for runtime optimization.

Comment: oooohhh I see .... you talk about `R` but in my code I have `Resource`, are those the same

Comment: You do not create the resource id numbers, just the human readable string. Then in your code, you use this string to reference it, at runtime, those resources are accessed by their integer ids.

Comment: Yes, the `R` file is the Java one, the `Resource` file is the matching C# one so you can code in C# against Java-based resources.

Comment: So the `ResourceDesigner.cs` file I show in my question is the file generated by `aapt / aapt2` ??

Comment: `aapt` generates the Java `R` class, `Xamarin.Andorid` has the `JavaResourceParser` parser that creates the C# version from that.

Comment: Yes, that is. I add the control and the Id Class is updated. Thanks.

Comment: So I guess Is just the syntaxis I have to follow?.  `android:id="@+id/myControlName` Because I change that line on the designer and the Class id change the constant to `myControlName`. Or I need to know something else about that?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza You do not need to know what the integer representation value of an `id` is, they will change, always use the human readable string-based name that you assigned the id (never hard-code the integer value as a replacement)