# 'Resource.Designer.cs' doesn't open with any 'designer'

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with the latest update.

I created a new Xamarin Forms solution (.net standard) and when I click on Resource.Designer.cs or when I try to "open with" with many options - I don't get any designer.

Since the text in the file says

```
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
```

Something must be missing.

How do I get the designer working?

Comment: You shouldn't edit this file.  It's auto generated based on the contents of the Resources folder.

Comment: @Jason Thanks. So it's not really a 'designer'-based file? `This is not the file you're looking for. Move along.` ?

Comment: The Resource.designer.cs file is automatically generated and managed by Xamarin.Android - you should never have to touch it. What are you trying to edit?

Comment: right, the naming is a little bit weird, as it's not tied directly to a single design file like most designer.cs files are.  But like all designer.cs files, it's not intended to be edited.

Comment: @MageXy I'm trying to make a simple sound. I added a file (beep.wav) to a folder `raw` inside `Resources`. And yet, when I run it on a device, VS tells me `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on `LoadApplication(new App());`. I have no idea what can be the problem, since I'm not even accessing the file yet. And I don't get any stack trace for it. So I thought maybe it has something to do with the file not being found...

Comment: @Jason Thanks. You can transform that into an answer.

Comment: It sounds like this is kind of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/372310). Try figuring out where exactly the null reference is coming from and go from there. From the small amount of code you've provided, it looks like it might be something during the construction of your App object.

Comment: @MageXy Definitely XY. I just thought it might have to do with this. But got my answer from Jason. As for `App` - it's not null. So I assume that during its creation there's something that goes amiss. I remember having something similar with a resource in the past. But in this case VS is not complaining about `Resource.Raw.beep` which I have in an event handler. I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: a wav file should probably be added as an asset, not a resource

Comment: @Jason Thanks. I followed this: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/media/audio/play_audio/ .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40451758/can-someone-actually-explain-the-workings-of-resource-designer-cs/40456727#40456727 might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to an answer in the comments this is *not* like the Visual Studio designer file. It should not be edited, but also does not have a designer mode associated with it.